# Find a value in one table that exists in multiple columns of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, exists

We have a table of CUSTOMER and a table of ACCOUNTS (there is no primary or foreign key in either table - long story!)

My data is such:

[image]

Accounts can 1, 2 or 3 owners.
I need to find which CUSTOMERS aren't associated with any account.

What I have tried:

[image: query]

But the query is literally taking forever - even when I restrict the subquery to return the top 10 rows.

I want to see returned in my search Danny, Emma and Fang

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: You query isn't going to exclude any rows.

Comment: You need to correlate the Customer records with the Accounts table in the subquery   `...where acct.Ower1 = cust.CustomerName OR acct.Ower2 =  cust.CustomerName OR ....`  Otherwise, you're essentially saying return everything in the Customer table when the Accounts table is empty.

Comment: Please add sample data and expected outcome (data in images don't count because that is unusable)

Comment: NOT EXISTS subqueries are typically _correlated_.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: On a side note: Are you sure there isn't a primary key on the tables? Is customer.customername nullable? It shouldn't be. Do you have a unique index on the column? You should. And bam there is your key! If it's the only unique key in the table, this makes it primary, too. So, I really wonder what that "long story" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to relate the subquery to your main query. Your query says: "Give me all customers provided there is no row in the accounts table." It should say "Give me all customers *for which* there is no row in the accounts table."

```
select cutomername
from customer c
where not exists
(
  select null
  from accounts a
  where c.customername in (a.owner1, a.owner2, a.owner3)
);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is my first time back in a technical role and I've been struggling....I really appreciate your succinct explanation

Comment: @DaleK apologies for images. It wouldn't let me save! It says that I had improperly formatted code! I checked and checked and redid and everything but it wouldn't save, I am returning to Stack Overflow after a long absence and am getting the feel for the new improved version.